# Unable to read csv with line breaks and blank lines

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel with multiline values with blank lines and line breaks in it...
I can read the multilines without blank lines/line breaks between them, but unable to read read blank lines/line breaks

Appreciate any inputs.
Sample Input below:

"Testing performed

in

an excel file"

Desired output: Testing performed\n\n\nin\n\nan excel file

code:

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(";");
    int headerrow = 0;
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        //Processing row
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        if (headerrow == 0)
        {
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                csvData.Columns.Add(field);
                //TODO: any logic
            }
            headerrow = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            csvData.Rows.Add(fields);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've always processed CSV files character by character, never line by line, using a state machine. As long as you know the last column doesn't contain new-lines, you can count your delimiters and include new-lines in columns before the delimiter count gets to your last column

Answer (score 0):

You need to Try/Catch malformed line exceptions